# Modify permissions on files without taking ownership

Tags: windows, file-permissions

There's a windows machine sharing a folder over samba and multiple users are leaving their files there.
I can access as the machine's local administrator.
Is there a way that I can access all the files, regardless of their owner, without the need of taking ownership.
I've been told I could use something like icalcs: The idea is to be able to read all files in order to perform file-level backup without disrupting the current permissions.

Comment: How is the backup performed?  Most backup software allows you to use backup privilege to access files regardless of the permissions.  Also, if you are just doing a file copy, the robocopy command has the `/b` option that bypasses file permissions.

Comment: ... it would be theoretically possible to modify the permissions without taking ownership, but there's no built-in solution for doing this, and I'm not personally aware of any third-party solutions either.

Comment: And what about using robocopy with the /b switch?